# No menu when trying to run Codeblocks

Tags: gui, 9.10

I installed codeblocks but the gui is not displaying well. There is no File, Edit, View, Search, Project etc but everything else is there. I am running 9.10.

Comment: Do you get any additional information when you run the GUI from the command line (debug output, warnings, etc)?

Comment: No it loads well but is incomplete.

Comment: Is this still a problem?

Comment: Hi, I had the same problem, I solved by installing the last stable from [here](https://launchpad.net/~damien-moore/+archive/ubuntu/codeblocks-stable), `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:damien-moore/codeblocks-stable`, `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get  install codeblocks`

Answer (score 2):

What version of CodeBlocks are you using ? The one in the Ubuntu repositories, or the latest release (CodeBlocks 10.05) ?

If you're using the 10.05, you need to install the corresponding wxWidget libraries (see the [CodeBlocks site](http://www.codeblocks.org/)), because the `wxWidgets` in the Ubuntu repositories are not up to date for the latest CodeBlocks.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your config file is messed up and the menu is being hidden.

Try removing `~/.codeblocks/default.conf`

Comment: Still not working. Could it be a problem with nautilus